# weird C++ pointer declaration

Tags: c++, pointers, declaration

I am writing a really small program about Depth First Search algorithm. At the end of program, a delete of the memory is required.

```
for(int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
    Vertex* temp1, *temp2 = graph->adjacentList[i];
    while(temp1 != NULL) {
        temp2 = temp1->next;
        delete temp1;
        temp1 = temp2;
    }
}
```

This code deletes the adjacent lists of the graph. The code can compile and run but with
runtime error. The error message is

> The variable 'temp1' is being used without being initialized.

Please look another piece of code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
    Vertex* temp1 = graph->adjacentList[i];
    Vertex* temp2 = graph->adjacentList[i];
    while(temp1 != NULL) {
        temp2 = temp1->next;
        delete temp1;
        temp1 = temp2;
    }
}
```

This code can compile and run and without any error message !
The only difference is the declaration. This is weird, at least for me.

Anyone can come up with an idea?

Comment: Thanks for Yu Hao and Ben for answering this question but I can only pick one accepted answer. Really sorry for the other one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Vertex* temp1, *temp2 = graph->adjacentList[i];
```

is equivalent to

```
Vertex *temp1;
Vertex *temp2 = graph->adjacentList[i];
```

You can see why there's an error says `temp1` is not initialized.

Comment: All true. What I don't see is any chance of the line `temp2 = temp1->next` ever running without run time error as the OP states.

Comment: Of course it can run without runtime errors - there is no guarantee that `temp1` would be an invalid pointer - it is a undefined one, it might land in the exact same memory location as a valid `Vertex` instance (very likely if there are no other objects being handled around), or even a totally bogus memory location that just happens to be readable at the `Vertex::next` member variable offset. Hence, the good practice is to do `Vertex *temp1=NULL`, making it *very* likely that it points to an unreadable memory area (most operating systems keep page 0 unmapped, ensuring that *NULL is invalid)

Answer (score 5):

In this code segment:

```
Vertex* temp1, *temp2 = graph->adjacentList[i];
```

You are not actually initializing `temp1`.

Consider the following:

```
int a, b = 2;
```

What is `a`? it is not `2`, it is un-initialized. Your second implementation is more correct.